# Mac Disk Utility converting MAC OS Journaled partition to NTFS-3G

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to install the Mac OS on my partition. In the setup, when I try to format that partition using the Journaled method, it erases it successfully. But when I select the partition, it shows me that it's NTFS-3G. What's going on?

Comment: what computer are you installing this on?

Comment: Are you using the Mac OS X disk utility to do this work?

Comment: Yes off course, i am using Mac osx disk utility. I am trying to install Mac OS on my system (Intel 2.9 Ghz core duo, Intel DG43NB mobo, WD Sata HDD). While installing setup does not find any partition. So i opened Disk Utility, Erase the partition on which i want to install os with method Mac OS Journaled. It erases successfully but when i again click on the partition it show me NTFS-3G